# Get elements by class name and change class name

Tags: javascript, wordpress, elementor

I have the following:

```
<div id="elementor-tab-title-1141" class="elementor-tab-title elementor-active"> 
     ...some stuff... 
</div>
```

I need a JavaScript code to look for all elements with that class, and remove the "elementor-active". So the code, after the JavaScript runs on page load, should look like this:

```
<div id="elementor-tab-title-1141" class="elementor-tab-title"> 
         ...some stuff... 
</div>
```

Here is what I tried:

```
function changeClass()
{
    var classNameArray= document.getElementsByClassName("elementor-tab-title elementor-active");

    for(var i = (classNameArray.length - 1); i >= 0; i--)
    {
        classNameArray[i].innerHTML = 
        getClassName(classNameArray[i].innerHTML);
        classNameArray[i].className = "elementor-tab-title";
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tries so far?

Comment: yea, add your code please.

Comment: Sorry! I edited my question and added what I've tried.

Comment: [Don't use `.getElementsByClassName()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952088/how-to-modify-style-to-html-elements-styled-externally-with-css-using-js/54952474#54952474).... ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the below steps

- Use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get all the elements with that `class`
- Then use `forEach()` loop on all the elements
- Use `classList.remove()` to remove that particular class

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('elementor-tab-title,.elementor-active')].forEach(x => x.classList.remove('elementor-active'))
console.log(document.body.innerHTML)
```

```html
<div id="elementor-tab-title-1141" class="elementor-tab-title elementor-active"> 
     ...some stuff... 
</div>
```

**Using jQuery**

You can do that bit easier using jQuery `removeClass()`

```js
$('.elementor-tab-title').removeClass('elementor-active');
console.log(document.body.innerHTML)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="elementor-tab-title-1141" class="elementor-tab-title elementor-active"> 
     ...some stuff... 
</div>
```

Comment: `.forEach()` is not supported on node lists in all browsers. You should convert the node list returned by `.querySelectorAll()` to an `Array` before calling `.forEach()`.

Comment: Worked great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `querySelectorAll()` to target all the elements, then loop through them to remove class using `classList.remove()` from the element:

```js
var elList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.elementor-tab-title'));
elList.forEach(function(el){
  el.classList.remove('elementor-active');
});
```

```css
.elementor-tab-title{
  color: green;
}
.elementor-active{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="elementor-tab-title-1141" class="elementor-tab-title elementor-active"> 
     ...some stuff... 
</div>
<div id="elementor-tab-title-1142" class="elementor-tab-title elementor-active"> 
     ...some stuff2... 
</div>
<div id="elementor-tab-title-1143" class="elementor-tab-title elementor-active"> 
     ...some stuff3... 
</div>
```

Comment: `.forEach()` is not supported on node lists in all browsers. You should convert the node list returned by `.querySelectorAll()` to an `Array` before calling `.forEach()`.